# SSL Prompting in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

How to disable the SSL pop up in IE on opening the website made in asp.net?!

Please see the following error by clicking on the link
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDkvk.jpg)

Comment: Conveniently, that error message is telling you **exactly what the problem is**. The website is being viewed from a **secure URL**, and you're including **insecure content** on the page. You need to deliver all content via https (eg, ensure nothing on the website is calling a http:// url, everything must be https://). The solution is not to disable the error message; the solution is to **fix your website**.

Comment: HI Christian,Thanks for your reply but How can i get the list of all the insecure content that is being hit by the website, so that i can move the insecure content(http) to secure content(https).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in IE's security settings for the Security Zone your website is in. Ideally, you probably shouldn't do this, however here are the steps:

1. Going  to Tools->Internet Options->Security
2. Select the Security tab
3. Click on the Internet zone icon at the top of the tab page
4. Click the Custom Level button
5. In the Miscellaneous section change Display mixed content to Enable

If necessary, repeat steps 1 – 5 for the Local intranet and Trusted sites zones.

Better option would be to work out what is causing the popup (usually referencing non-ssl content from your SSL website) and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above you need to ensure you don't load http resources in your https document as that can destroy the https security promise. You need to change your http resources to use https. You can find out the list of troublesome http resources by pressing F12 in IE to bring up the developer console and then navigating to your page. You'll see messages like the following in the developer console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIr7J.png?s=24&g=1
File: stackoverflow.com
```

For more information on why its bad to load http resources in an https document as well as how to address the issue see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx